# Jquery php mysql login does send data to mysql but doesn't return right value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Question: I can see that the data is getting written to the database but $action doesn't become register in the insert.php call from the html file and hence php JSON return is NULL ??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Load </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h3>Login Page</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
                </div>                                 
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                     
                    <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>
                </div>
                <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
            <a href="#registerp" data-role="button">Register</a>
        </form>                             
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="registerp">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>Register</h3>
    </div>
     <div data-role="content">
         <form id="registerform" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname"/>
                </div>         
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="lname" id="lname"/>
                </div>  
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="uname">User Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="uname" id="uname"/>
                </div>                  
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                     
                    <label for="pwd">Enter your password:</label>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="pwd" id="pwd"/>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email"/>
                </div>
                <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="register" value="Register">
            </fieldset>
        </form>      
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Page footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>Welcome Page</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        Welcome
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Page footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#login', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
        if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
            // Send data to server through the ajax call
            // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
                $.ajax({url: 'check.php',
                    data: "action=login&" + $('#check-user').serialize(),
                    type: 'post',                  
                    async: 'true',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.status) {

                            $.mobile.changePage("#second"); 

                        } else {
                            alert('Log on unsuccessful!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action               
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });                  
        } else {
            alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
        }          
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });   
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#registerp', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#register', function() {
    if($('#uname').val().length > 0 && $('#pwd').val().length > 0){
            // Send data to server through the ajax call
            // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
                $.ajax({url: 'insert.php',
                    data: "action=register&" + $('#registerform').serialize(),
                    type: 'post',                  
                    async: 'true',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner

                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.status) {

                            $.mobile.changePage("#second"); 

                        } else {
                            alert(' Try again later ! Server is busy !');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action               
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });                  
        } else {
            alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
        }          
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While my PHP Script is simple as shown below... please help

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("...............", "...........", ".........","........");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pwd']);

$action = $_POST['action'];
// Decode JSON object into readable PHP object
 //$formData = json_decode($_POST['formData']);

$sql="INSERT INTO userdb (username, fname, lname, password, email) VALUES ('$uname', '$fname', '$lname', '$password','$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);

if($action == 'register'){
$output = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Registered');
}

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Insert php script doesnt work while the below register php script works fine.

```
<?php   
// We don't need action for this tutorial, but in a complex code you need a way to determine Ajax action nature
 $action = $_POST['action'];
// Decode JSON object into readable PHP object
 //$formData = json_decode($_POST['formData']);

// Get username
$username = $_POST['username'];
// Get password
$password = $_POST['password'];

$db = @mysql_connect('..........', '........', '..........') or die("Could not connect database");
@mysql_select_db('users', $db) or die("Could not select database");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `userdb` WHERE `username`= '$username'");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$pass_ret = $r['password'];

// Lets say everything is in order
if($action == 'login' && $password == $pass_ret){
$output = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Login');
}
else
{
$output = array('status' => false, 'message' => 'No Login');

}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dumping($_POST);`'ing your data to see that all the required fields are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug in Firefox to inspect the response from the AJAX call. You set the call to expect JSON as the data type and you also use it as JSON. The problem is you have this line:

```
echo "1 record added";
```

Which is output before your JSON. So your response probably looks something like:

```
1 record added{"status": false, "message": "No Login"}
```

This isn't valid JSON and it will not parse, and thusly this line will never work:

```
if(result.status) {
```